# jQuery plugin for code snippets

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin that I can use to write code and allow the user to edit, similar to the one that is given below.

Can you recommend any plugins?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: like [this](http://www.steamdev.com/snippet/) but editable yes?

Comment: by that I mean do you want it to have syntax highlighting (and if so what languages), line numbers or just plain text box with the addition of a copy button?